# How to make Textmate detect code after the filter :coffeescript?

Tags: textmate, haml, coffeescript

Using the Haml :javascript filter, the code following the filter is accurately detected as javascript.  This isn't happening with the :coffeescript filter.  How do I make Textmate recognize this code as coffeescript?  (I already have the [coffeescript bundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle) installed.)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to edit the HAML bundle syntaxes to do that, probably just by copying the JavaScript language delimiter and modifying it to work with Coffeescript.

http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/Bundles